# Trying to connect to com.android.npp using ACR122 but get error saying [NFCSTATUS_INVALID_STATE]

Tags: java, android, nfc

I've been using the javax.cardio package to receive an NDEF message from my Nexus S through my ACR122U. I've created an Android Beam app that sends a simple text "Hello!" when the intent filters for a NDEF_DISCOVERED tag. When using the TgGetData (0x86) command I seem to get:

```
NfcP2pLinkManager(7588): Sending ndef via SNEP
NFC JNI(7588): Socket not connected
NFC JNI(7588): LLCP Link deactivated
NFC JNI(7588): LLCP Connect request failed
NfcService(7588): LLCP Link Deactivated message. Restart polling loop.
NFC JNI(7588): phLibNfc_Llcp_Close() returned 0x0001[NFCSTATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER]
NfcP2pLinkManager(7588): Failed to connect over SNEP, trying NPP
NdefPushClient(7588): about to create socket
NfcP2pLinkManager(7588): LLCP deactivated.
NdefPushClient(7588): about to connect to service com.android.npp
NFC JNI(7588): phLibNfc_Llcp_ConnectByUri() returned 0x0011[NFCSTATUS_INVALID_STATE]
NdefPushClient(7588): couldn't send tag
NdefPushClient(7588): exception:
NdefPushClient(7588): java.io.IOException
NdefPushClient(7588):   at 
com.android.nfc.nxp.NativeLlcpSocket.connectToService(NativeLlcpSocket.java:47)
```

The APDU workflow I'm following for the ACR122 is basically:

```
1) TgInitAsTarget = 0xD4, 0x8c
2) TgGetData = 0xD4, 0x86
3) TgSetData = 0xD4, 0x85, 0x81
4) TgGetData = 0xD4, 0x86
```

Does anyone know why I cannot connect to the "com.android.npp" service on the Nexus S?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out why my issue was occurring. I don't need to send a CONNECT APDU once I recieve the first set of bytes from teh phone via TgGetData. After this first stream of bytes, just send a CC APDU or a CONNECTION COMPLETE. For those who need help, the APDUs should be :

```
1) TgInitAsTarget 0xD4 0x8C
2) TgGetData 0xD4 0x86
3) TgSetData (CC) 0xD4 0x8E - no need to send the service name. Simple the DSAP-CC-SSAP bytes. That's it.
4) TgGetData 0xD4 0x86 - you should get your data in this byte stream.
5) TgRelease 0xD4 0x8E
```

**REMEMBER:** You must switch the DSAP and SSAP that you get from the phone around to use in your TgSetData. Good luck!

Comment: Please can you copy/paste all the bytes sequence of your communication? I have spent a week trying to send an NDEF message from my phone to my ACR122U reader but has been impossible :(

Comment: @OverMind, I don't really have these sequences anymore as I've moved on from this project, but I'll do a quick dig through my archives to find them. I was working on Nexus S at the the time, so these sequences may not be necessarily the same for your phone and/or OS.

Answer (score -1):

See [this](http://code.google.com/p/ismb-npp-java/wiki/NppFromACR122ToPhone) NPP implementation for ACR122 how to do it.

Comment: This person has very similar code to what I have. I used the following ADPU:
(byte)0xd4, (byte)0x8e --- TgSetData
(byte)0x05, (byte)0x21, (byte)0x06, (byte)0x0f, 
(byte)0x63, (byte)0x6f, (byte)0x6d, (byte)0x2e, (byte)0x61, 
(byte)0x6e, (byte)0x64, (byte)0x72, (byte)0x6f, (byte)0x69, 
(byte)0x64, (byte)0x2e, (byte)0x6e, (byte)0x70, (byte)0x70

This connects to the service and I receive the ndefmessage, but it still doesnt complete the Beam. It throws out an error called "NdefPushServer: badly formatted NDEF message, ignoring" - an IOException that I suspect fails the beam. Any idea why?

Comment: Could it be that your "Hello!" message is not encapsulated in an NDEF message (i.e. using a Text RTD)?

Comment: I'm trying to recieve the Hello message from my phone which the Android SDK is nice enough to provide APIs to convert to NDEF. I've used this from my Nexus to another Nexus and the message beams properly. I'm wondering if I need to create an com.android.npp service for the ACR itself that the phone can connect to... the only reason I say this is because of the following debug line -
    NdefPushClient(7588): about to connect to service com.android.npp

Comment: Hi @NFCguy, first of all, welcome to stackoverflow. I just read through some of your answers and I'm pretty glad you've joined. Small note: please do not just post links as answers, as links get lost etc., please put a bit of the solution in the answer.

Comment: This seems to be a better thread about connecting the ACR122U with the android nfc service. 

http://www.libnfc.org/community/topic/401/p2p-communication-between-android-phone-and-nfc-reader/

I'm not sure how to connect to the nfc service... I'm using the following APDUs that I thought would connect:

{ (byte)0x11, (byte)0xa0,(byte)0x06, (byte)0x0f,(byte)0x63, (byte)0x6f, (byte)0x6d, (byte)0x2e, (byte)0x61,(byte)0x6e, (byte)0x64, (byte)0x72, (byte)0x6f, (byte)0x69,(byte)0x64, (byte)0x2e, (byte)0x6e, (byte)0x70, (byte)0x70};

Which is the "CC" APDU with SN: com.android.npp

Comment: I must be doing something wrong --- I send a TgInitAsTarget PDU successfully. After this, I do a TgGetData PDU and get back:

d5:87:00:11:20 --- that's a CONNECT with the appropriate DSAP of 000100 and SSAP of 100000. After this, I send back a CONNECTION COMPLETE using:
d4:8e:81:84 -- that's a DSAP of 10000 and SSAP of 00100.
After this I send a TgGetData using d5:87 and then the android log gives me the problem in my first post above. Any one have any ideas why?